# How can i change the layout of notification email in com_contact?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I'm using Joomla 3.4.1, and I want to change the layout and style of the notifications email for the Contact component (I want to add some disclaimer text that we always use in our emails).
When someone sends a message in the contact form, and the admin gets an email, that's the notificacion i'm trying to change.

Which files should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by creating a language override, as the content of the Joomla system emails comes from language files. I'm not sure exactly what notification you want to override, but take a look at the file

```
ROOT/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_user.ini
```

Remember you should never edit core Joomla files. Locate the string(s) you need, and create an override.

You can create an override from the Joomla admin area. Under "Extensions" click on "Language Manager".

Or do it manually but creating the following file (if it doesn't already exist):

```
ROOT/language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini
```

In this file you can add your overrides, and they will not be deleted when you update Joomla.

**Update:**

An easier alternative would maybe be to use a Joomla form component (I like [BreezingForms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/breezingforms) a lot, but there are many other alternatives). It's possible to configure both user and admin emails, and even attach additional files to the message, like a PDF or image.

Comment: Thank you johanpw
What i'm trying to do, is: when someone sends a message in the contact form, and the admin gets an email, that's the notificacion i'm trying to override.
The language files only allow me to change the text, not add or change the order of the information in the email.

Comment: @hachipark I see. You could try editing `components\com_contact\controllers\contact.php` and add your disclaimer to the `$body` variable, but that's a core hack and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

got to `components\com_contact\controllers\contact.php` and edit to whatever format you wish. Always works for me. **back up the file first**

Comment: Probably not a great idea to edit core files though. An override as suggested by @johanpw is safer.

Comment: all he wants is a working solution... Both are awesome :)

Comment: I didn't say any answer was incorrect. Simply advising that editing core files is not advised, for obvious reasons. Nonetheless, an override is much more 'awesome' in my opinion.